# eclipse sometimes does not update search results as I make edits

Tags: eclipse, search

So I use Ctrl+H to search for a variable. For refactoring purposes, I do a ctrl+h on a term (lets say "user") and then do some refactoring. I want that the results in the search results should update automatically as I make my refactoring (lets say I replace user with "blah" so the concerned lines should disappear automatically). It does work sometimes but does not work many other times. I use Ruby or Web perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Alt+Shift+R*** on variable and it will replace all over the file variable is used.

Comment: so I'm not looking for actual refactoring. It is more in rb and html files where I have to do selective replace, which is why the question. Without thinking about refactoring, too, I would love to get the answer to this.

Comment: You can use ctrl + F and enter find and replace with fields and do check CaseSensitive and Whole word checkboxes so that the search will not search for exact words, though need to be careful to replaceall.